# Query que busca quantidade de items de uma coluna em uma tabela com mesmo nome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Olá, estou tentando buscar a quantidade de registros com o mesmo nome, de uma determinada coluna na minha tabela Lead na base de dados em um período(mês).
Segue minha classe, quero buscar somente do campo "Origin"

```
    public class Lead
{

    internal Lead(INotificationHandler notificationHandler)
    {
        _notificationHandler = notificationHandler;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public TreatmentOfInterest TreatmentOfInterest { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    public Guid CalendarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
}
```

Minha DTO para retorno:

```
public class LeadOriginDto 
{
    public LeadOriginDto()
    {
        Origins = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string> Origins { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? CalendarId { get; set; }
}
```

Minha interface de repositório deixei esses dois métodos para saber qual eu teria melhor performance:

```
    public interface ILeadRepository : IRepository<Lead>
{
    Task<int> LeadsCountForOrigin(DateTime date);

    IQueryable<Lead> LeadsCountForOrigin(LeadOriginDto origin);
}
```

E minha classe de repositório onde quero criar a query:

```
internal class LeadRepository : Repository<Lead>, ILeadRepository
{

    private readonly DbSet<Lead> _leads;

    public LeadRepository(IDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        _leads = context.Set<Lead>();
    }

    public Task<int> LeadsCountForOrigin(DateTime date)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public async IQueryable<Lead> LeadsCountForOrigin(LeadOriginDto origin)
    {
        var date = new DateTime();

        var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
        var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

        IQueryable<Lead> query = _leads
            .Include(search => search.Patient)
            .Include(search => search.Calendar);

        //var nameOrigins = (from o in _leads 
        //                   group o by new { o.Origin} into grp
        //                   select new Lead { Origin = grp.Sum(s => s.Origin)}).ToListAsync();

        //var nameOrigins = from o in _leads.Cast<string>()
        //                  group o by o into g
        //                  select new { Lead = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
        var nameOrigins = await _leads.CountAsync(lead => lead.Created >= firstDayOfMonth && lead.Created <= lastDayOfMonth && lead.Origin)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key);

        //var originsCount = 
        //(nameOrigins.Count() > 0)
        return nameOrigins;
    }
}
```

Os trecho que estão comentados foi da maneira que tentei fazer e não consegui realizar de fato a query que busca a quantidade de nomes repetidos na coluna Origin em determinado período de cada mês.

Exemplo:

No mês de `Janeiro` foi registrado

```
10 - Joao 
5 - Maria
2 - Jose
```

`Fevereiro`

```
20 - Maria
15 - Jose
3 - Joao
```

Comment: Não seria o caso de agrupar e contar?

Comment: Seria o caso de buscar na base os registros de uma coluna específica dentro da tabela, e ver a quantidade de registro com o mesmo nome.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz este select na base para buscar os registros da tabela LEAD na coluna Origin e abaixo vou deixar a minha query, que me da um retorno com status 200 mas sem os dados da coluna que eu quero.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]